# WebStorm Async Await debug Node.js Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, sails.js, webstorm

I can't debug an async "await" instruction. I always have a promise.
I have seen that there is an "Async" button where the red square is in the picture but I don't have it.
[image]

Here is the run config: 
[image]

When I evaluate the expression: 
[image]

In the documentation of WebStorm you can see that there is the "Async" checkbox.
[image]

Does anyone have an idea how I can debug and the result of an await?

Answer (score 7):

**Async** checkbox has been removed from debugger UI, async stack traces are always enabled.
To evaluate the value of promise use `await` operator, like `await getPromise()`. Unfortunately due to JavaScript engine limitations (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=833928) value of Promise can be obtained only when execution is not stopped at a breakpoint:( You can try evaluating the value during code execution in debugger (when execution is not suspended)